# Kotlin: MutableSharedFlow BufferOverflow behaviour on first emissions

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a following code snippet:

```
val flow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()

launch {
    repeat(10) {
        delay(100)
        println("emitting$it")
        flow.emit(it)
    }
}
    
launch {
    flow.collect {
        delay(1000)
        println("a$it")
    }
}

launch {
    flow.collect {
        println("b$it")
    }
}
```

I would expect output to be like:

emitting0
b0
a0
emitting1
b1
a1
...

Because of `BufferOverflow.SUSPEND` which causes emitter to wait until events are consumed.

The actual output follows this pattern with exception for the first two elements, so the actual output is:
emitting0 b0 emitting1 b1 a0 (now it starts following the behaviour I expected) emitting2 b2 a1 emitting3 b3 a2 ...

What causes the second item emission? Shouldn't it wait for first item to be consumed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does wait. What's confusing you is the `delay(1000)` before printing `a#`. By the time it prints `a#` 1 second has passed since it started consuming it. Swap them and you'll see it clearly.

```
flow.collect {
    println("a$it")
    delay(1000)
}
```

You can also print something else after an item has been emitted just to make it even clearer:

```
repeat(10) {
    delay(100)
    println("emitting$it")
    flow.emit(it)
    println("emited$it")
}
```

This is what it outputs:

```
emitting0
a0
b0
emited0
emitting1
b1
a1
emited1
emitting2
b2
a2
emited2
...
```

Comment: Thanks, it clarified it a bit, but I think I'm still misunderstanding when an event is treaten as consumed and when new emission can start. I've made outputs a bit cleaner:

I've added `println("emited$it")` as you mentioned and I also added `println("starts waiting for a$it")` before delay happens in my code.

Now it prints: `emitting0` `starts waiting for a0` `b0` `emitted0` `emitting1` `b1` `a0` `starts waiting for a1` and so on.

So event is treaten as consumed when execution in `collect { }` starts not when it's finished?

Comment: @jakubledwon When `collect` starts, no matter what it does, the producer/sender "understands" that the item has been consumed by that consumer, so it can emit more items if all consumers have consumed the last emitted item.